# Requiring recaptcha on form submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, recaptcha, unobtrusive-validation

We just added google recaptcha v2 to our site. Its working fine but we would like to require reCaptcha on form submit. We are using the default unobtrusive jquery validation. When the user doesn't fill in the reCaptcha widget then `g-recaptcha-response` will be empty. I've seen other threads asking how to validate reCaptcha with javascript. We definitely don't want to do that we want to still validate it from the server end but want to stop spam bots from trying to submit the form (hence making it required).

It looks like mvc just adds a `data-val="true"`and `data-val-required="my error message"` to every required field but i'm not sure how to hook in reCaptcha. I also want to ensure the following code will still work unchanged:

```
if ($(form).valid()) {
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had to resolve the same issue and came up with the following approach that works. In summary, add a hidden field on which jquery unobtrusive validation operates, and populate/clear it on recaptcha callback & expiry.

Script:

```
function reCaptchaVerify(response) {
    $('#hidden-recap').val(response);
}

function reCaptchaExpired () {
    $('#hidden-recap').val('');
}

function reCaptchaCallback () {
    grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
      'sitekey': RC2KEY,
      'callback': reCaptchaVerify,
      'expired-callback': reCaptchaExpired
    });
}

$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: null });
```

And within the form, add the field:

```
<div><input type="hidden" name="hidden-recap" id="hidden-recap" class="text form-control" value="" maxlength="500"
data-val="true" data-val-required="Please complete reCaptcha" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="hidden-recap" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
```

Notes

- The hidden field is simply there for client-side validation, to check
  that reCaptcha has been completed; the server validation can ignore
  it.
- The final script line .setDefaults is needed because by default 
  unobtrusive validation ignores hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a perfect solution but i found something that will work for now:
http://www.ivanthevariable.com/combining-googles-recaptcha-and-jquery-validate/

**html:**

```
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{YOUR-SITE-KEY-HERE}"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
var validator = $("#add-conference").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore",
   rules: {
       city: {
           required: function() {
               if ($("#city-name").val()) {
                   return false;
               } else {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       },
       country: {
           required: function() {
               if ($("#country-name").val()) {
                   return false;
               } else {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       },
       "hiddenRecaptcha": {
           required: function() {
               if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                   return true;
               } else {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
   }
});
```

What i didn't like about this solution was that i had to turn unobtrusive validation off. Hopefully someone comes out with a solution that will work for unobtrusive validation until then i will use this solution.